# Is there any way to search for or find questions or answers with unapproved edits?

Tags: support, editing

I want to help out and try new features by approving good edits. I'd there any way to find edits that have not been approved? Also how do I approve them if I find them?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a privilege that is unlocked at 2,000 rep. At that time you will have access to the Suggested Edit queue, where you can view edits that have been suggested and approve them, improve them, or reject them as appropriate.

So keep asking and answering things, and you will get there!

Comment: Or asking things!

Answer (score 0):

Note:  I'm trying to answer the more general question, "What can I do to help?"

At 500 reputation, you will have access to the review queues.  Then you will at least be able to see when you'll be able to approve edits.  At 500, you can help with the First Post and Late Answer queues.  You'll be able to see how many posts are in the other four queues, but you won't be able to view those posts until you get 2000 and 3000 reputation respectively.

You can read more about what privileges you get at what reputation on the [privileges help page](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/privileges).

Personally, I've gotten most of my reputation recently from suggesting edits.  This won't get you to 2000, since the maximum (1000) is lower than that, but it is a way that you can contribute and advance your reputation at the same time.